# HTML Title Image

Tags: html, favicon

I want to have an image on the title in an HTML page (i.e on the tab along with the title). How can I do that?

Comment: You mean like this?:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: You'll find more information about favicon with the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912708/favicon-not-showing-my-icon-is-no-good

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a favicon to a static HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page)

Answer (score 54):

What you need is a favicon.ico file.
Just put it in the root of your site and link to it in the header of your page

```
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
```

You should put it in the root of your site and name it favicon.ico because some browsers look for it even if you don't link to it on your pages.

Answer (score 24):

For cross browser compatibility, seems to be needed two lines for for favicon:

**TITLE**

```
<title>PAGE TITLE HERE</title>
```

**FAVICON**

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://domain and path/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://domain and path/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

**FAVICON GENERATOR:**

[DYNAMIC DRIVE](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/)

Comment: That favicon generator doesn't seem to exist anymore

Answer (score 5):

Please add a line similar to this within the head-elements:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/somwhere/icon.ico">
```

.ico files work best among old browser, but of course you can use png and jpeg files, too.

Answer (score 4):

You are wanting to set a favicon.  Here is the tag to do that:

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Add this tag to your `<head />` and it will instruct browsers of the site to download the image referenced in the href.