# how to add favicon + URL

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML title image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103490/html-title-image)

I needs to site URL with Favicon, please guide me how to add it. Like if you see gmail 
thanx

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103490/html-title-image)

Answer (score 4):

Google: http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon