# Adding a favicon to a static HTML page

Tags: html, static, favicon

I have a few static pages that are just pure HTML, that we display when the server goes down. How can I put a favicon that I made (it's 16x16px and it's sitting in the same directory as the HTML file; it's called favicon.ico) as the "tab" icon as it were? I have read up on Wikipedia and looked at a few tutorials and have implemented the following:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

But it still doesn't want to work. I am using Chrome to test the sites. According to Wikipedia .ico is the best picture format that runs on all browser types.

### Update

I could not get this to work locally although the code checks out it will only really work properly once the server started serving the site. Just try pushing it up to the server and refresh your cache and it should work fine.

Comment: who don't you tell any of your friend to check it for you on some other system, same issue is with one of my client my system showing up fine and he's complaining favicon not showing up, i mostly use first one of you example and its correct. best of luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Comment: Your example is working now on Chrome.

Comment: Interesting, the live website served up the favicon just fine, but when viewing the file locally, and not serving it through a local server (b/c it's simple static site - yea!), the favicon didn't show.  In hindsight it makes sense, servers auto serve it up.  Adding `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">` to the `head` (next to the 32, 16, and 180 favicon variation `link`s) solved the issue locally.  Since I'd included `link`s for the larger icon sizes, and the manifest, I didn't think twice about why `favicon.ico` wasn't showing up! :-)

Answer (score 1191, accepted):

You can make a .png image and then use one of the following snippets between the `<head>` tags of your static HTML documents:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://example.com/favicon.png"/>
```

Comment: did you try putting "shortcut icon" in the rel= for your ico links and put a / before favicon.ico on both just to state that it is in the webroot dir?

Comment: yip tried that too.. man lol i rate i am going to restart it all and then try boot up and see if maybe its cashing wrong or something..

Comment: i just ran it with firefox and chrome and have literaly copied your code aswell no luck. DOH!

Comment: I swear - i had the same problems after adding the code - it took maybe a day for the browser to display the icon instead of the grey box it usually has - try dumping ur browser cache history etc

And if u copied my code make sure u change example.com to ur domain lol

Comment: cool beans well thanks dude i dont know if it is going to get any better i will vote up on both of the answers and just check up on it tomorrow i guess lol thanks for help :)

Comment: There is a redundant / in the top line href argument. Once I removed it it works like a charm. Should be: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">

Comment: and what if you don't know the exact link that will be used?
(some users use www.domain1.com and others use www.domain2.com)
That makes option 2 difficult..
Option 1 does not work for ie 10/11 here.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon says to include a `profile` attribute in the `head` tag... is that necessary?

Comment: you're adding an extra slash '/' to href="favicon.png"

Comment: Be sure to add this in the <head>PUT HERE</head> section!

Comment: thanks it worked for me. But, why did you kept two <link> tags in your answer only 1 tag was enough for me

Comment: Do you add this in the head section? Needs a bit more detail.

Comment: HTML5 standardised this to `rel="icon"`: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-icon Please update your answer to reflect this!

Comment: Just FYI, you do not require a 16 X 16 image, I use a 400 x 400 image and it works just fine.

Comment: Chrome seems to have some sort of deep cache as CTRL+F5 wasn't enough for it to pick up my amended code, but I know it'll work for others as fresh computers / browsers displayed the favicon fine.

Comment: [Apparently, `shortcut icon` is harfmul...](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon)

Comment: Do you need both of those lines?

Comment: href without slash worked for me. `href="favicon.png"`, not `href="/favicon.png"`.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) says that apple iOS/Safari don't use `rel="icon"` but instead use the non-standard `apple-touch-icon` and `apple-touch-startup-image` rel types. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4
Please update this answer to account for this.

Comment: For Chrome, open dev tools and right click the reload button, which will give advanced options. One of these options will be "empty cache and hard reload", which is useful to reload the favicon.

Answer (score 279):

Most browsers will pick up `favicon.ico` from the root directory of the site without needing to be told; but they don't always update it with a new one right away.

However, I usually go for the second of your examples:

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
```

Comment: does it have to be befoer the meta data or the script tags?? or not a problem

Comment: As long as its in the <head> section, it shouldn't matter - because its not reliant on something else to work.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) says to not use `shortcut` anymore.

Answer (score 142):

Actually, to make your favicon work in all browsers, you must have more than 10 images in the correct sizes and formats.

I created an App ([faviconit.com](http://faviconit.com)) so people don´t have to create all these images and the correct tags by hand.

Hope you like it.

Comment: Loved the app, no bs - straight to it, and the image can be edited before creating all the favicons +1 to you for saving me a bunch of time :)

Comment: Agreed, this is a great app. While I don't think all those image sizes seem quite necessary, I love that it generates them and the required markup etc. Thanks!

Comment: But it is proprietary.

Comment: It doesn't work, gives `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

Comment: @Eduardo, I read on faviconit.com that the service will be terminated on 03 October 2023. Can you please put the sources into GitHub? Maybe someone might want to continue providing this service?

Comment: @Laszlo, here are all the versions I ever attempted to do: https://github.com/russoedu?tab=repositories&q=faviconit&type=&language=&sort=

The "php" version was the one live

Answer (score 69):

## Usage Syntax: <sub><sup>`.ico`, `.gif`, `.png`, `.svg`</sup></sub>

This table shows how to use the [`favicon`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) in major browsers. The standard implementation uses a link element with a `rel` attribute in the document's `<head>` section to specify the file format and filename/location.

> **Note** that most browsers will **give precedence to a `favicon.ico` file** located in the website's root (therefore **ignoring** any icon link tags).

```
                                         Edge   Firefox   Chrome   I.E. Opera Safari  
 -------------------------------------- ------ --------- -------- ----- ----- ------ 
 <link rel="shortcut icon"               Yes    Yes       Yes      Yes   Yes     Yes
   href="http://example.com/myicon.ico">                          
 
 <link rel="icon"                        Yes    Yes       Yes      9     Yes     Yes
   type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"                  
   href="http://example.com/image.ico">                        

 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"    Yes    Yes       Yes      9     Yes     Yes
   href="http://example.com/image.ico">   

 <link rel="icon"                        Yes    Yes       Yes      11    Yes     Yes     
   href="http://example.com/image.ico"> 

 <link rel="icon" type="image/gif"       Yes    Yes       Yes      11    Yes     Yes
   href="http://example.com/image.gif">      

 <link rel="icon" type="image/png"       Yes    Yes       Yes      11    Yes     Yes
   href="http://example.com/image.png">     

 <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml"   Yes    Yes       Yes      Yes   Yes     No
   href="http://example.com/image.svg">
```

---

### File format support

The following table illustrates the image file format support for the `favicon`:

```
                                         Animated                                
  Browser             ICO   PNG    GIF    GIF's   JPEG   APNG   SVG   
 ------------------- ----- ------ ------ ------- ------ ------ ------ 
  Edge                Yes   Yes    Yes    No      ?      ?      ?     
  Firefox             1.0   1.0    1.0    Yes     Yes    3.0    41.0  
  Google Chrome       Yes   Yes    4      No      4      No     No    
  Internet Explorer   5.0   11.0   11.0   No      No     No     No    
  Safari              Yes   4      4      No      4      No     No    
  Opera               7.0   7.0    7.0    7.0     7.0    9.5    44.0
```

---

### Browser Implementation

The table below illustrates the different areas of the browser where favicon's are displayed:

```
                      Address     Address bar 'Links'                       Drag to  
  Browser             Bar         drop-down     bar       Bookmarks   Tabs   desktop  
 ------------------- ------------ ----------- --------- ----------- ------ --------- 
  Edge                No            Yes         Yes       Yes         Yes    Yes      
  Firefox             until v12     Yes         Yes       Yes         Yes    Yes      
  Google Chrome       No            No          Yes       Yes         1.0    No       
  Internet Explorer   7.0           No          5.0       5.0         7.0    5.0      
  Safari              Yes           Yes         No        Yes         12     No       
  Opera               v7–12: Yes    No          7.0       7.0         7.0    7.0      
                      > v14: No
```

Icon files can be **16×16**, **32×32**, **48×48**, or **64×64** pixels in size, and **8-bit**, **24-bit**, or **32-bit** in [color depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth).

While the information above is generally correct, there are some variations/exceptions in certain situations.

> <sub><sub>[image: img]</sub></sub> **See more detailed information at the source on [Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Browser_implementation).**

---

## Update: <sub><sup>*("more info")*</sup></sub>

- See Google's "new" (2019) criteria to [**Define a favicon to show in search results**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9290858).
- You can retrieve (programmatically or manually) **Google's cached favicon** for ***any*** domain with a URL such as: [`https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com)

  Using the above URL directly in an `<img>` tag returns: " [image] ".
- I've used [**realfavicongenerator.net**](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) a couple times; it's very thorough, generating/customizing every possible favicon variation you might need for maximum compatibility.  (However, if you're seeking a *single* favicon image, this is might *not* be the tool for you!)  For simple file conversion (eg., `PNG` to `ICO`, etc) I like [**onlineconvertfree.com**](https://onlineconvertfree.com/convert-format/png-to-ico/).

Answer (score 60):

Convert your image file to Base64 string with a tool like [this](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) and then replace the `YourBase64StringHere` placeholder in the below snippet with your string and put the line in your HTML head section:

```
<link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,YourBase64StringHere" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

This will work 100% in browsers.

Comment: I found another tool that does the conversion in JavaScript without transferring data to the server: https://jpillora.com/base64-encoder/ Additionally, it handles multiple files by drag and drop. Save the page to use it locally.

Comment: imho, best solution, because it honors the "static html" page and is completely self contained within the document.

Comment: Best solution. Works with png files as well . <link href="data:image/png;base64,YourBase64StringHere" rel="icon" type="image/png" />

Comment: This will cause a long string to be added to every page. Use inline base64 for small images that are rarely sent to the user.

Comment: This way your favicon is never cached, you send the whole string to the client each time, IHMHO using a url and therefore the browser cache feels 'cleaner/ better'

Comment: This works! Example: `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAACkSURBVDhPY/hPIYAb8IihhCQMAxgGvEtbA+b/PPMYLgZigwBIDiYGAygGvDCeAOVhNwAEQGpwGvB55nEoD7cBIDVYDQCZjKwQlwEgNrJL4QZ87NgHZUEALgNAAFkt3AB0gM8AZIASBjAMAtgMQFcDAoPIAHSAzQBsAKcB33ffghsAYuMCOA0ARRXMAPQoRgYYBnwo3wrXiI5BcugApwuIA///AwDHE3Yy3CghqAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">` -- Image base64 encoder: https://www.base64-image.de

Answer (score 16):

[As recommended by W3.org](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon), you can use the `rel` attribute to achieve this.

Example:

```
<head>
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
...
```

Answer (score 15):

If the favicon is a png type image, it'll not work in older versions of Chrome. However it'll work just fine in FireFox. Also, don't forget to clear your browser cache while working on such things. Many a times, code is just fine, but cache is the real culprit.

Comment: That's fine; it's very hard to install/keep an old version of Chrome anyway

Answer (score 10):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/favicon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico"/>
```

This worked for me

Comment: While this may work, you can't use image/png as the MIME Type - because it's incorrect considering you're using .ico

Comment: Does "worked for me" include Safari on iOS?

Answer (score 5):

I know its older post but still posting for someone like me.
 This worked for me

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='favicon.ico' />
```

put your favicon icon on root directory..

Answer (score 5):

### Minimal favicon without "type" attr

```
<link href='favicon.png' rel='icon' />
```

You can even omit the quotes, but not recommended in production.

Answer (score 4):

As per OP's update, It was not showing up locally, but as per OP's update, once I uploaded it to the server, it was fine.

Since this is a simple, static html website, I have the luxury of working on it without running a local webserver.
A webserver will generally automatically serve up the favicon, if there is one, by default.

But when not running a webserver, the browser itself will not just read the directory looking for additional files, say a favicon.ico, unless it is listed in the html document.

So, while I had the following items in the `head` tag:

```
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
```

I did not *also* include a reference for plain 'ol `favicon.ico`.
Even though, the `favicon.ico` file was included, in addition to the images listed above.

Once I added the following line:

```
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

It *did also* show up in my browser, when I viewing the *local* file, even when *not* serving it through a local server.

So icon showed up fine when it ran on the live server, but not locally.

I mention this explicitly because the favicon generator I used, kindly supplied the code, icons, manifest, and instructions.  However, while it included the `favicon.ico` image, it did not include a `<link>` to that file in the code to add to the `html` document.
I guess that service presumes `favicon.ico` will automatically be served up and used by all browsers by default, so only the "alternate" versions needed to be explicitly added to the head tag.
Evidently, they don't consider that when viewing files locally (aka not serving them up locally), we aren't interested in seeing the favicon?

Comment: "A webserver will generally automatically serve up the favicon" -- technically, the browser requests it. The server doesn't just serve it without it being requested by the browser. Maybe the browser doesn't do this for `file:///` urls.

Answer (score 3):

as an additional note that may help someone some day.

You can not echo anything to the page before:

```
Hello
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/webico.ico"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/webico.ico"/>
```

will not load ico

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/webico.ico"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/webico.ico"/>
Hello
```

works fine

Comment: That is because it is supposed to be in the head section of an HTML document, and is ignored by most browsers if it isn't.

Comment: Yea, I just wanted to put this here in case anyone ran into a problem.  My problem was the "hello" was some debug code and had me stumped for a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I used `convert -resize 16x16 img.png favicon.ico` (on linux konsole) to convert my image, and 
add `<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">` to my header and everything work perfect.

Comment: You need a multi-layered icon with sizes larger than 16px, for higher DPI screens and who knows what else -- mobile "install to home screen" use cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the favicon into the root/images folder with the name favicon.ico browser will automatically understand and get it as favicon.I tested and worked.
your link must be www.website.com/images/favicon.ico

For more information look this answer:

[Do you have to include <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644684/do-you-have-to-include-link-rel-icon-href-favicon-ico-type-image-x-icon)

Comment: Where does the `/images/` come from? You probably have a `base` element in your page. By default, favicons serve from `/`. But this is the old way; domains typically hold more than one site now. It's best to add the icon meta tag.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if your site is running as a `subfolder` ie:

```
http://localhost/MySite/
```

You will need to take that into account. If you are doing so from an `ASP.NET`app all you need to do is add a `~` to the front of the URL:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: `~` is not a thing in the world of URLs. `/favicon.ico` is correct. Is ASP.net doing some rewriting of urls? Check the actual page source as served, with "Inspect Element" or "View page source".

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET MVC converts a ~ to convert the physical path of the file to its actual online url.

Answer (score 0):

Note that FF fails to load an icon with a redundant `//` in URL like `/img//favicon.png`. Tested on FF 53. Chrome is OK.

Comment: That's not really an *answer* as much as it is a *comment*.  (See "[answer]".)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the `<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favi.ico"/>`