# HTML- Adding or controling Icons in Title Bar

Tags: html, css, icons, titlebar

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="c.ico"/>
    <title>A title</title>
</head>
```

This will add an icon to the left of the title up in the title bar.
Can I add another?
Or change the positon of the icon to display to the right of the text?

```
<head>
    <title>A title</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="c.ico"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="c.ico"/>
</head>
```

The above changes nothing, and I haven't found any answer for this, probably because nobody does this and this may be useless.
But I was still wondering.

Using CSS with this (like float:right or border-radius) didn't work at all and I couldn't find any thing useful in the reference for link.

Comment: No, you only get one. There's no reason you couldn't make one **combined** image though and use that. Oh and you can't style the `title` element.

Comment: Ah, make an image that is composed of two images, nice workaround, although long images may be weird, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786937/add-image-in-title-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The favicon is not actually part of the web page, it is just an image that the browser use to display your page title more friendly. How the image is displayed is up to the browser.

Comment: So, hypothetically, a browser can be created to support doing whatever you want in the title without extending html or css?

Comment: Yes, for example some browser do not need the <link> tag, they take whatever .ico file that is located at the website's root. Have a look at wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon