# Set title image in css

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to set a title image using css within my custom theme.

I know i can set a title image for an app manually but i want to do it within a theme using css. I have managed to set the background colour blend and the font colour but i cant work out how to set the image.

I have tried the following with no luck.

```
.sheet-title-logo-img {
background-image: url("https://www.qlik.com/us/-/media/images/qlik/global/qlik-logo-2x.png?h=94&w=308&la=en&hash=12D34BE69F...");
}

.sheet-title-logo-img.ng-scope {
background-image: url("https://www.qlik.com/us/-/media/images/qlik/global/qlik-logo-2x.png?h=94&w=308&la=en&hash=12D34BE69F...");
}

.sheet-title-logo-img.ng-scope {
background-image: url("https://www.qlik.com/us/-/media/images/qlik/global/qlik-logo-2x.png?h=94&w=308&la=en&hash=12D34BE69F...") !important; 
}
```

Has anybody managed to achieve this and can point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: What is the 'title image' for an 'app'?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't specify the image/favicon in css. 
You would have to do it like this.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="your_image_path_and_name.ico">`

You should consider searching before posting a question because there are a lot of unanswered questions that actually don't have a solution.

Here is a link to a similar question: [Add image in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786937/add-image-in-title-bar)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
#sheet-title .sheet-title-logo-img {    
    background-image: url(https://www.qlik.com/us/-/media/images/qlik/global/qlik-logo-2x.png?h=94&w=308&la=en&hash=12D34BE69F...) !important;
}
```

Comment: well, read the question first, he didn't ask to change favicon or page icon but only qlik sheet image