# Get Image inside of title (HTML)

Tags: html, favicon

I need a image to be displayed with the title, and I found many stackoverflow questions on how this is done. [What is currently the best way to get a favicon to display in all browsers that support Favicons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-get-a-favicon-to-display-in-all-browsers-that) and [Add image in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786937/add-image-in-title-bar). I did what both of these said (add a .ico file and a .png file), and came up with this (inside the head of the html):

```
     <link rel="icon" href="/client/imgs/favicon.png" type="image/png" /
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/client/favicon.ico" />
     <title>Amaze</title>
```

I have both of those files, but the image won't show up in localhost or after I deploy it to heroku (https://labyrinth-sweeper.herokuapp.com/). What part did I miss / mess up?

Comment: First of all, a `>` is mising at the end of line 1 in your code. Regards

Comment: ctrl+F5 to clear the cache and refresh

Comment: Please right click on the tab in the chrome window and say reload. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The favicon is visible to me. Maybe there is an old icon in your browser cache? Try something like `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/client/favicon.ico?v=2" />` to force your browser to refresh the icon.