# Customizing bookmark icon in bookmark toolbar

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, cross-browser, firefox-addon

Can I customizie bookmark icon in my browser ? I can rename my bookmark item in bookmark toolbar of my browsers . But I have no idea which way I can modify it's icon image ( *may be favicon of it's site* ).

Please check below image..

[image]

It is an example as I really want to do ***(may be another icons and it is create by renaming***) .

I would like to insert my customize image icon. Can it be possible ? Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The bookmark icon is the favicon of your site. To add a custom favicon to your site, follow the instructions here: [Adding a favicon to a static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page)

Basically, create a 16x16 pixel image, save it as a PNG called `favicon.png`. Put that file in the root of your web site and then add the following to the `<head>` section of your website:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/png">
```

**Be sure to add that code to every page.**

Also note that it can take a little bit for the icon to update in your browser. Clearing your browser's cache, and sometimes manually trying to load the `favicon.png` file by going to that file in your browser, then refreshing a few times, can force the update.

Comment: sorry sir , I am asking concern only with my browsers , not any language such as java or javascript or HTML . I would like to customize bookmark icon in my browser. for instance : "aaaaaa" addons can customize your browwers icon. And now I can see google site bookmark item with yahoo site favicon. :)

Comment: Ah I see. You don't want to customize your own site's icon for everyone else, but merely customize other sites for yourself? Sorry for the confusion. That differs per browser, but you might find results with a simple web search on the topic.

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, this might help you, although it's not really easy to do: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3032/google_chrome_how_to_change_icons_on_the_bookmarks_bar/

Comment: yes, Thanks sir . it is greatly useful link for me. But I have not still test it yet because I am using **Mac** .

Comment: I think it would be more trouble than its worth in that case. Google Chrome is designed to pull that icon from the website, and not really allow you to customize it. I'm afraid I don't have any more suggestions for you. Best of luck, though. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: but I really appriciate all of your useful informations . Thanks. Have a nice day sir.