# When I visit django Project WebPage, the log remind me:not found favicon

Tags: python, django, favicon

Why django project receive favicon request?

like this
    **Not Found: /favicon.ico

    [23/Jul/2016 11:37:11] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1941**

Where did the request come from?

I find request from my browser.
Can I control it? How to close it?
Thanks everyone that care this question...(Bab English, sorry)

Comment: You probably haven't made migrations

Comment: This request comes from the browser.

Comment: Yes, I found it, comes from the browser, can I control it?
Thanks everyone..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message that you are seeing is from Django, letting you know that a request was made for the favicon.ico file, and that it returned a 404 error.

The request for the favicon icon is usually made by the browser when you first access the site. This is the little icon that you see next to urls, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBX7A.jpg

The error is correctable via many ways, as explained here(basic html): 
[Adding a favicon to a static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page)

Since you are using django I would recommend taking a look at this guide as well(django version): http://staticfiles.productiondjango.com/blog/failproof-favicons/

Basically you need to make the favicon.ico icon available to the requester via HTML code, like this: 
`{% static 'favicon.ico' %}`: if within a template and the icon in the static folder

or this: `<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please collect all your static data using "python manage.py collectstatic"

If you have already done that, make sure favicon.ico is part of static directory