# Favicon not working when redirecting github page with mask (my own domain)

Tags: html, url, github-pages, favicon

Good night, i have a page mounted on **github pages:**
https://ludicultura.github.io/ludiweb/

If you open that link the favicon works perfectly, but i buy a domain on **goDaddy** so i can redirect that page, masking it with my domain:
http://ludicultura.com/
and there the favicon it doesn't work.

(Both of them links are up, so you can check them.)

I tried the option of adding a "?" to the end of "href"

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico?">
```

And algo changing my image to png:

```
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
```

But nothing works, what is happening?

Source and records of the repository and all the changes:
https://github.com/ludicultura/ludiweb

Comment: I could not find favicon on both provided links.

Comment: @frnt You can't see it on any of the first two links?
Check the repository, there it is the favicon.

Comment: No favicon on both provided links.

Comment: @frnt I checked it on chrome console, but i do can see it, it is on line 11-15.

Comment: Check this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ludicultura.github.io/ludiweb/, change your favicon url to `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/favicon.ico">`.

But framing ludicultura.github.io/ludiweb/ in ludicultura.com is not a good practice.

You'd better setup your custom domain correctly after reading [this documentation on github pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/).

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Still not working, i think the problem is some dns configuration, something like the CNAME.

Comment: `dig ludicultura.com` returns `ludicultura.com. 578 IN A 184.168.221.19` it is supposed to be 192.30.252.153 or 192.30.252.154. So yes it is a DNS problem. Maybe you just have to wait for the change replication.