# How to assign an icon to a web application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, web-applications, wamp

My web application is deployed in the `www` folder of `Wamp`. It is a `PHP` web application using `Codeigniter` as framework. So when I run the app then the icon displayed on the browser's tab is Wamp's icon !

[image]

Here is the project structure under the project's root folder :

[image]

So how can I change the app's icon ?

Comment: Just a tip: I notice your ip is in your url. Which means you have not set your base_url on config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/papsp/';` You should set it because if not some links like css, images etc will not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page  `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url('favicon.ico');?>" type="image/x-icon" />`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yes you are right , but at this time my boss was testing the app from his computer , so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a favicon into the webroot? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

You can generate them easily [here](http://www.favicon-generator.org)

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the location of your .ico icon file in the meta tags.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/path/to/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Comment: @pheromix no it is not, but it has to end in .ico

Answer (score 1):

Add in head tag below meta tags. Then Add images to Project folder it's works fine.

```
     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" sizes="16x16">
```