# Is it possible to style the browser tab and bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

A while back I downloaded a Chrome extension which allowed me to customize my browser tabs, background, bar, even the color of the font that displayed in the tab. This extension is called "Theme Creator" on Chrome.

So I was wondering, is it possible to use code to style the tabs, bars, font color of the browser itself in css or html? Or does this extension only work because it *is* and extension in Chrome?

I am new to coding by the way, so bear with me, I am not sure how everything works just yet, I would just like to know if this is possible because that would be amazing for a site that I am trying to create.

Comment: No, that is not possible. CSS and HTML are sandboxed and cannot interfere with the appearance of the browser tab bars. Those styles are typically dictated by the OS (and therefore having no single standard that unites them), and the possibility of a Chrome extension to change the appearance does not rely on these web technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, but you can style the scroll bar and favicon :D

Link to the answer about scroll bar styling: [CSS customized scroll bar in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div/14150577#14150577)

Changing the favicon: [Adding a favicon to a static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page?rq=1)

Comment: A little off-topic but I remember styling the scroll bar back when MySpace was huge!

Comment: alright, well that sucks, but thank you for the links! I will check them out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the meta tag to color the tabs

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#c80a49"/>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color

Answer (score 0):

No. That is handled by the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have control of would be the favicon