# How to add a favicon?

Tags: html, favicon

I am creating a website and i want to add a favicon to the title of the browser. i tried this code but nothing happened.

```
 <html>
  <link rel = "icon" type = "image/png" href = "/icon.png">
  <head>
    <title></title>

 </head> 
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a favicon to a static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need to put it inside your head element

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="YOURICONPATH/icon.png">
    <title></title>

 </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.png">
```

Putting this inside your header section will set up a favicon at the top left of the tab on your website. Make sure to change the example picture to the image of your choice.

Comment: It's the head section. `header` is an HTML5 tag; putting it in there doesn't do anything.