# Title and Favicon Doesn't display in PHP

Tags: php, favicon, page-title

Here is the title and link I used with the header, but I just get the word "Document" instead

```
<title>Chicken and Waffle | Local 360 | Gunyen&lt;/title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/gunyen%20logo%20dark.png">;
```

sample: https://gunyen.com/post/local360chknnwfl.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apply full path like http://https://gunyen.com/post/images/gunyen%20logo%20dark.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code again! This is the page source code I see in my browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="docsearch:language" content="en">
    <meta name="docsearch:version" content="4.3">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/gunyen%20logo%20dark.png"/>
    <!--https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag#directives-->
    <!--<meta name="robots" content="index, follow, archive">-->
    <meta name="robots" content="nofollow, noindex">
...
```

As you can see, there are 2 head blocks!

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will pick up favicon.ico from the root directory of the site without needing to be told; but they don't always update it with a new one right away.

However is a correct way to achieve your task with the name of *favicon.ico*:

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='images/gunyen/logo/favicon.ico' />
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943834/6366593