# I don't understand what's wrong with my HTML code for adding my favicon to my website?

Tags: html, web, favicon

Here is my code:

```
<link 
rel = "shortcut icon" 
type = "image/x-icon" 
href = "C:/Users/SOMEBODY/Desktop/SOME FOLDER/ANOTHER FOLDER/favicon.ico"/>
```

I also have the favicon in the same folder as my website. When I open the .HTML file, it doesn't show me the icon.
Btw, my website is unpublished to the web.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a favicon to a static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `favicon` in the same folder as you `HTML` file you can use a relative path like bellow

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">
```

I presume the issue is related to the path `C:/Users/SOMEBODY/Desktop/SOME FOLDER/ANOTHER FOLDER/favicon.ico` you should escape all `space` of the path for it to be correctly interpreted.

You should also reference the absolute file using `file` protocol like this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="file://C:/Users/SOMEBODY/Desktop/SOME FOLDER/ANOTHER FOLDER/favicon.ico"/>
```

Comment: Ok, I will try that, thanks for helping, I'll post again about if it works, again thanks! :)

Comment: It turns out that I needed to put my website on the internet for it to work

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and what I did was:

- Open the .ico file on your browser by selecting the address or by dragging.
- And select the image url, paste it in your html file.
  This time it should work. Although, they both should look same, but they are not.
  **And remember that sometimes Mozilla Firefox do not load favicon if it is stored locally.**