# On the top left corner of my chrome tab there is an earth symbol, how can I change that?

Tags: html

can someone please advise how best to change whatever that symbol is on websites I create?

[google chrome tabs, left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9WVt.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a favicon to a static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page)

Answer (score 1):

This is called a favicon !
You can just use this in your page's `<head>` :

```html
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png" />
```

(You just have to replace the url and `image/png` by `image/jpg` if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **"Favicon"**

> A favicon (favorite icon) is a tiny icon included along with a
> website, which is displayed in places like the browser's address bar,
> page tabs and bookmarks menu.

Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Favicon

You will have to create different icons in different sizes for multiple devices. See this page for generating icons https://favicon.io/ and the HTML you will need