# Favicon is Not Showing Up

Tags: html, css, web, icons, favicon

I had Almost done Everything.
But my Favicon is Still Not Showing Please Review My Code. I had Downloaded Favicons from Fivcon.io and Copied that downloaded folder in my Website Folder After extracting then Pasted the Given Code By Them. But it Still Doesn't show Favicon.

Here is My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon-32x32.png"  type="image/x-icon">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content=
        "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        <title>
        Survey
    </title>
    
    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\css.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">
    <h1 class="heading">Covid Survey Form</h1>

    <!-- Create Form -->
```

Comment: Did you try opening in Incognito window?
Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Is the favicon file in the **same directory** as the website?

If it is, try changing `<link rel="icon" href="favicon-32x32.png"  type="image/x-icon">` to `<link rel="icon" href="favicon-32x32.png"  type="image/png">`.
Also, please try to minimize the number of link tags.

Else, bring the favicon file to the same directory as the website.