# Logo not showing on Google Search results

Tags: html

I recently made a website using HTML/CSS/and JS. I have deployed it and given it a domain name and everything works fine. However, the logo image of my website isn't showing up in google search results. I've added the favicon link, and the logo does show when I hover over a tab. It's just not showing in google search results. Any way I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Here is the favicon link I put in my header:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/website.png" />
```

Comment: Try `rel="icon"` instead of `shortcut icon`. Also a .png file has the mime-type of `image/png` instead of `image/x-icon`.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943801/3144667) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google needs time to read the information and update it in the search, now try to properly make sitemap.xml to facilitate the reading of information for search engines, as well as add the site in google search results through the Google Search Console