# How to put images next to the title's tab at the top of the screen in HTML

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SamUn.png)
There is no IMAGE title for the tab, as It shows the default.

I looked but couldn't find any tutorials online, only the ones that ALIGN images, but I do not need to know that.

(Not aligning images putting it next to the tab's title)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page Title</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

What you are looking for is called a favicon. The favicons are usually put in the same folder as your index.html document titled just `favicon.ico` but can be a png, jpeg, etc.
Here would be a tutorial related to what you want, https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_favicon.asp

also here is a stack overflow post about it:
[Adding a favicon to a static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page?rq=2)

Above is an example. The link tag should be in the head section of the html and reference to the image (the favicon) would be in the href="favicon.ico" in the same link tag, as long as the image you put in the same folder is titled `favicon.ico`