# Add Favicon to Website

Tags: html, favicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML Title Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103490/html-title-image)

Can someone please tell me how to make icons appear on browser tabs in PHP?

I want my icon to appear on the tabs when my site is being accessed.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Simply put a file named `favicon.ico` in the webroot.

If you want to know more, please start reading:

- [Favicon on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)
- [Favicon Generator](http://www.favicon.cc/)
- [How to add a Favicon by W3C](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) (from 2005 though)

Comment: or if you don't want to work with .ico files `<link rel=icon href=/favicon.png>`

Comment: @Subin Sebastian, your comment should be an accepted answer. Thank you. :)

Comment: not working for me on opera browser nor edge. Need to remove the / to make it work

Answer (score 156):

1. This is not done in PHP. It's part of the `<head>` tags in a HTML page.
2. That icon is called a favicon. According to Wikipedia:

   > A favicon (short for favorites icon), also known as a shortcut icon, website icon, URL icon, or bookmark icon is a 16×16 or 32×32 pixel square icon associated with a particular website or webpage.
3. Adding it is easy. Just add an `.ico` image file that is either 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels. Then, in the web pages, add `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">` to the `<head>` element.
4. You can easily generate favicons [here](http://www.favicon.cc/).

Comment: Should not it be simply `icon` instead of `shortcut icon`?

Comment: @bažmegakapa It can be either.

Comment: The default seems to be /favicon.ico if not specified.  Wouldn't having a relative url like the one in this answer break pages which are deeper than the root level?

Comment: for those who want to add a favicon to a web application such as express in nodejs. I got it to work by placing the favicon file in the root of the public folder from where your static files are served. Then added this line to the head section of my html file. `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

Comment: What if I have a 64x64 png?

Comment: @kapa virtually whatever you put in the `rel` would work as long as the word icon is there